# When can $\frac{3}{n}$ not be written as the sum of two reciprocals of natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory

> Show that the set of natural numbers $n$ for which $\frac{3}{n}$ cannot be written as the sum of two reciprocals of natural numbers ($S = \left\{n \mid \frac{3}{n} \neq \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}\right\}$ for any $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$) is not the union of finitely many arithmetic progressions.

I first wanted to see which values of $n$ all $\frac{3}{n}$ to be written as the sum of two reciprocals of natural numbers. We have $\frac{3}{n} = \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} \iff 3pq = n(p+q)$ where $n,p,q \neq 0$. What do I do from here?

Comment: Note that $S$ is divisor-closed: if $n\in S$ and $m\mid n$, then $m\in S$. I wonder if this is already enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Above you've written $S$ as the set of demonators $n$ such that $\frac3n$ that *can't* be written as $\frac1a+\frac1b$; according to that definition, $30\notin S$.

Comment: If $n$ is a multiple of $2$ or $3$, a solution always exists. If a solution exists for $n$ and $k>0$ is an integer, then a solution also exists for $kn$.

Comment: The equation $$3pq-np-nq=0$$ is equivalent to the equation $$(3p-n)(3q-n)=n^2$$. This should help.

Comment: For every number $n$ divisible by prime of the form $3k+2$ with $k>0$, a solution exists.

Comment: A rephrasing: when does $3/n$ not have a length-$2$ Egyptian decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

Some initial observations:  $\frac 32=\frac 11+\frac 12, \frac 33=\frac 12+\frac 12$, so $2$ and $3$ are not in $S$.  Any multiple of a non-member is a non-member because if $\frac 3n=\frac 1p+\frac 1q, \frac 3{kn}=\frac 1{kp}+\frac 1{kq}$

I claim primes that are $1 \bmod 3$ are in $S$ and primes that are $2 \bmod 3$ are not in $S$.  This says any number which has a factor not equal to $1 \bmod 3$ are not in $S$.  I do not resolve numbers like $91=7 \cdot 13$, but we do not need to do so for this problem.

Suppose $n$ is prime and greater than $3$.  From $3pq=n(p+q)$ we see that $n$ must divide one of $p,q$ and we can let it be $q$.  Then write $q=nr$ and multiply the original relation by $q$ getting $3r=\frac {nr}p+1$. $p$ cannot divide $n$ because if both $p,q$ do the right side is at most $\frac 2n$, so $p$ must divide $r$.  Write $r=sp$ and substitute in, getting $3sp=ns+1$  Now we can see $s=1$, so $r=p, 3p=n+1$  To have a solution we must have $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ an in that case we have the solution $\frac 3n=\frac 1{\frac {n+1}3}+\frac 1{\frac {n(n+1)}3}$.  An example is $\frac 3{11}=\frac 14+\frac 1{44}$

We can use $\frac 3{10}=\frac 14+\frac 1{20}$ to show that not all numbers $1 \bmod 3$ are in $S$.  Any other arithmetic progression than $1,4,7, \dots$ will eventually hit a number not in $S$, so it will contain only finitely many numbers, and a finite number of them will be finite.

Comment: I couldn't follow the point "Any other arithmetic progression..." Can you please elaborate on how we finish. Thank you.

Comment: @caffeinemachine:  any progression not a subset of $1,4,7,\ldots$ will contain a prime that is equivalent to $2 \pmod 3$

Comment: I get that. Thanks. What I am not able to see is how we rule out the possibility that finitely many sub-progressions of $1, 4, 7, ...$ partition $S$.

Comment: I haven't covered that.  I believe you can show that any infinite subprogression will have a number of the form $p^2q$ where $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$